# How are the first mods chosen for brand new stack sites?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I've recently started following and participating in some Area 51 stack sites and one is currently in the commit phase. It wasn't inherently obvious who will be moderating it and how those people are chosen.

What is the process for selecting the first moderators for new sites?

Comment: It's not related to Area 51, moderators are chosen when the site is already launched. (before graduation though)